# Form based authentication in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, forms-authentication

I am using in sharepoint 2013. I have a web application with Form based authentication.I have changed in web.config of central admin, my web application and security token service application with the membership and role provider settings but cannot login. The screenshot shows the error on login.
[image]

But searching fba users through people picker finds the name correctly.
[image]

Comment: I have followed this link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/gg252020(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: First, its not finding an FBA user, second verify the default providers for .NET Users and .NET Roles in IIS.  This guide is one of the better ones [Link](http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/configuring-forms-base-authentication-for-sharepoint-2010-using-iis7/)

Comment: @Dovahkiin I have set default provider for .net user and roles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have it setup correctly in at least one web.config file (Central Admin or your web application - wherever you are using the people picker).  However multiple web configs are used for SharePoint.  The login uses the settings from the SecurityTokenService web.config file, so there is probably a problem with the membership or database connection settings in that file.

You may want to double check your settings against this guide:

http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/configuring-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2013-part-1-creating-the-membership-database/